# How to use same class but different implementation in android multi flavor project

Tags: java, android, android-build-flavors, android-flavors, build-variant

I have 3 flavors.

> flavor1
>
> flavor2
>
> flavor3

and MainActivity for all flavors. I want the same implementation for flavor1 and flavor2 and different for flavor3. If i add separate MainActivity in flavor3/java/com/sample/MainActivity it show "**Duplicate class found in the file**" and the folder structure is following.

main/java/com/sample/MainActivity

> flavor1
>
> flavor2
>
> flavor3/java/com/sample/MainActivity

**Do I need to add the MainActivity in all flavors?**

Like :

main/

> flavor1/java/com/sample/MainActivity
>
> flavor2/java/com/sample/MainActivity
>
> flavor3/java/com/sample/MainActivity

But doing this every time I have to update when change in flavor1 and make that change in flavor2. is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to add the MainActivity in all flavors?

Yes.

> But doing this every time I have to update when a change in flavor1 and make that change in flavor2. is there any solution?

Have `MainActivity` be as small as possible, delegating to other classes as needed. So, the `flavor1` and `flavor2` implementations of `MainActivity` might delegate to some other class that resides in `main`, while the `flavor3` implementation of `MainActivity` does something else.

Comment: Or have a BaseActivity that that MainActivity classes extend. Most of your code changes should go in BaseActivity and you're good to go. If this is just a matter of different configuration values then consider putting them in BuildConfig and keeping just one MainActivity